# Upstart error terminated with status 1

Tags: node.js, ubuntu-10.04, upstart

I have an ubuntu 10.04 server and tried to create an upstart script:

```
description "node-workerListener"
author      "me"

start on startup
stop on shutdown

script
        # We found $HOME is needed. Without it, we ran into problems
        export HOME="/var/www"

        exec sudo -u www-data /usr/local/bin/node /var/www/vhost/node/test/workerListener.js 2>&1 >> /var/log/node/helloworld.log
end script
```

This should start a node script, which works, if I start it manually on the command line. But when i try to "start node-workerListener" I get the message "node-workerListener start/running, process 1323", but it doesn't.

In /var/log/syslog: "...init: node-workerListener main process (1317) terminated with status 1"

What can I do?

Comment: Issue happens when you run "sudo -u www-data /usr/local/bin/node /var/www/vhost/node/test/workerListener.js 2>&1 >> /var/log/node/helloworld.log
end script"
On the command line?

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you resolve it?

Comment: Probably has something to do with the use of sudo... try "sudo start node-workerListener"

Comment: Found this line somewhere on the internet `start on started mountall` commented by `# used to be: start on startup //
# until we found some mounts weren't ready yet while booting`.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can also use **forever** https://github.com/nodejitsu/forever to run the node process.

Here is a detailled article : http://blog.nodejitsu.com/keep-a-nodejs-server-up-with-forever